# pecl command not found with Amazon AMI and PHP7

Tags: php-7, pecl

I'm running the Amazon Linux AMI 2016.09.1 (HVM), SSD Volume Type

I've run:

```
yum update
yum install php70
yum install php70-gd php70-mysqlnd php70-fpm php70-pecl-apcu php7-pear php70-devel
yum install php70-soap
```

When do do a

```
php -v
7.0.14
```

and

```
apachectl -V
Server version: Apache/2.4.25 (Amazon)
```

but when I try to run 'pecl'  I get "command not found"

I've confirmed that each package was installed.  Not sure what package I'm missing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's `pecl7` not `pecl`

try to run you command using `pecl7 install xxx`

if the problem still exists, run `pear7 config-set php_suffix -7.0 system` and check again.

Comment: I feel sheepish now.  Thank you!